# C - Error: expected a ")"

Tags: c, error-handling, compiler-errors, syntax-error, runtime-error

I have written code in C, but it gives a particularly strange error message:

`lcd.c(618): error:  #18: expected a ")" if(character_segment_data & (0b10000000>>width_counter))`

Code:

```
void lcd_putchar(char character,int forground_color,char background_color_activation,int background_color)
{
int temporary_color;
unsigned char width_counter,length_counter;
char character_segment_data;
for(length_counter=0;length_counter<16;length_counter++)
{
    character_segment_data=font8x16[character-0x20][length_counter];
    for(width_counter=0;width_counter<8;width_counter++)
    {
        if(character_segment_data & (0b10000000>>width_counter))//line 618-origion of error
        lcd_write_pixel(((int)x_text*8)+width_counter,((int)y_text*16)+length_counter,forground_color);
        else
        {
            if(background_color_activation)
            {
                temporary_color=lcd_read_rdr();
                temporary_color=lcd_read_rdr();
                lcd_write_wdr(temporary_color);
            }
            else
            lcd_write_pixel(((int)x_text*8)+width_counter,((int)y_text*16)+length_counter,background_color);
        }
    }
}

if(++x_text>40)
{
    x_text=0;
    if(++y_text>15) y_text=0;
}
}
```

This line `if(character_segment_data & (0b10000000>>width_counter))` generated the error. What is the origin of the error and how can I resolve it?

Thank you.

Comment: I think the error comes from the next line as it's got too many parentheses, and could've missed one easily.

Comment: There is no problem I can see in this code. Are you sure it was saved before compiled? The other thing is to check whether your compiler is supporting the binary literals (it is not obvious)

Comment: That line is missing a closing semicolon. (Edit - no it's not but the lack of `{}` confused me. Don't omit `{}`.)

Comment: @StoryTeller Are you sure? I can't see it.

Comment: Thank you @ForceBru. If the error comes from the next line, why the IDE point to line 618?

Comment: @slim which line? It's `if` condition

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: Again, are you sure your compiler supports binary literals?

Comment: Thank you @EugeneSh. I examined the code with `0x80` rather than `0b10000000` and worked! Why compiler supports hex literals and not binary literals? It's very strange. ِAgain thanks for your help.

Comment: Nothing strange. C standard is defining hexadecimal constant notation, but the binary is not there and therefore just an extension of some compilers. (just for reference: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1)